# AddDbContext is not a member of IServiceCollection .Net Framework

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection

I have a .Net Framework 4.8 Webforms application that I need to extend.

A decision was made by the company that all new works would be done in C# rather than VB, and all new projects would be a min .Net 2.0 Standard so that the webforms 4.8 project can be migrated over to a .Net Core \ .Net6 Web Application

It has no DI in place at the moment and I am looking at introducing IServiceCollection using something like this in the .Net Framework 4.8 Global.asax file

```
IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddScoped<ICsvDataReader, CsvDataReaderService>();
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDBContext>(x =>
{
    x.ConfigureWarnings(w => w.Ignore(SqlServerEventId.SavepointsDisabledBecauseOfMARS));
    x.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
});
var defaultResolver = new DefaultDependencyResolver(services);
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(defaultResolver);
```

The problem I am having is that I am getting an error

> AddDbContext is not a member of IServiceCollection

However, this is something that I thought was and is standard in IServiceCollection.  When I saw I was wrong I have added a couple other nugets that I thought would do the trick.

Microsoft.EntityFramework.SqlServer
EntityFramework

But this error still appears.  I would be grateful for some pointers on what I need, or more importantly where I have gone wrong.

I am also open to the idea of using something like Unity or someother provider if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

It means either one of two things:

1. you are missing `using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` declaration on the top of your C# file that gives the exception, as the `EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions` that contains this [AddDbContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.entityframeworkservicecollectionextensions.adddbcontext) extension method lives in this namespace
2. You are missing a reference to the [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/) from your project.

Please note that only Microsoft Entity Framework Core versions up to [3.1.24](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/3.1.24) support `.NET Standard 2.0`. Any newer version requires at least `.NET Standard 2.1` or `.NET 6`, but .NET Framework 4.8 does [not](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard?tabs=net-standard-2-0) support `.NET Standard 2.1`. This might actually be the problem. You might have concluded you added the newest version to your project, but either the NuGet installation failed, or the project is currently not compiling because it is incompatible with that NuGet package.

Comment: I have this `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`, and the reference to the core project, I highly doubt that would work in the .Net 4.8 project where this would need to be registered in the Global.asax file

Comment: Which version of the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` NuGet package did you install?

Comment: 6.0.4 is what I would have tried, but the global.asax file is in a Webforms project (main project) which is .Net Framework 4.8. 

When I tried to add `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` i get `Could not install package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 6.0.4'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.8', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author`

Comment: Yes, that is what I am trying to say: you will have to downgrade to  3.1.24 to get this to work in .NET Framework 4.8. It's either that, directly move to .NET 6 for this new project, or switch to Entity Framework 'classic'.

Comment: A move down isnt something we can do, but there is currently talk of bringing up from .net 4.8 to .net6